# Reading/writing X.509 certificate piece by piece

Tags: x509

I want to write my own X.509 certificates from scratch for test purposes or, alternatively, modify existing ones (and re-sign them). I want full control over each field, including the ability to write invalid data for some fields. Is there a library or tool that deals with the high-level structure of the certificate and signing and encoding the whole thing at the end, while letting me have fine-grained control over the data?

I know OpenSSL can dump the whole certificate as text, but that still leaves me to work out which bytes in the certificate correspond to which text. Something like the Wireshark Packet Details/Packet Bytes view would be very useful: [image]

This decodes the meaning of some bytes in the TCP packet and highlights exactly where they are in the packet. Is there anything similar for X.509?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you should look at [RFC 5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt%20rfc%205280). Unfortunately that doesn't really solve your problem, since any modifications that you make will invalidate the signature on the certificate.

Depending on how fancy you want to be, you will have to use some software to generate the certificates for you. OpenSSH is one option, but there are others.